# How to set directories of a file from which I append?

Tags: python, scripting, path, append

I am making a project where I use materials from an external file.Both my files are present in a folder. I append them. While scripting, I specified the absolute path of the file. But if I copy the folder with both project and materials file into another system. Then appending them shows an error because the path that I specified is no longer the materials path. So, can anyone help me out so that I can set up the path such that it imports material from within the folder that contains these files?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about python programming, not specifically Blender related. You should try on stackoverflow, perhaps.

Comment: Would [making the paths relative](https://imgur.com/a/ZSIASVI) before computer transfer help?

Comment: If it's an addon?  setting a base folder via a user preferences path string property could be an option worth considering.   Will require reset once each time for new system when enabling addon.

Comment: How would blender know where this folder is? It can't track files. If I understand your question correctly, I don't think its possible. The best solution is to store those assets in a folder with a shared parent to the blend file that uses them (and then use relative paths), or to manually update the paths each time you move the files between systems.